# Why is there no styling on the Wordpress dashboard for MAMP localhost, happening only on Chrome?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, mamp

I've installed MAMP according to the Wordpress Codex installation procedure and it seems to be running fine from /Users/username/Sites and using port 80 for Apache.

I've created new databases from the phpMyAdmin interface and successfully installed Wordpress into them using the famous 5-minute install.

The new sites show up nicely but when I access the Wordpress dashboard area, this is what I see:
http://www.evernote.com/shard/s19/sh/49a6c28c-0170-467a-a3f5-433d8ca4d4df/1863e78f5f870c7db6a41e0f18c03fca

The strange thing is that the Dashboard is showing up fine in Firefox. It's Chrome that's displaying this inconsistency. I've tried clearing Chrome's cache a number of times but it's not helping.

Could anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 5):

In order to fix this issue you need to add

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

To your wp_config.php file.

Comment: This worked for me as well.  I have 10+ local sites that all work fine except one.  I added this to the wp-config and its working fine.  Could really use an explanation.